# does dharma have stages?

Tags: vishnu, dharma, kali-yuga, buddha

the eternal dharma, known as sanatana dharma, is a concept in hinduism. eternal is often confused with unchanging, constant, but it might be more correct to say without beginning-end, forever.  I've been wondering does the dharma of hinduism have stages?  What else would explain the various incarnation of visnu? don't these manifestations give us a hint of god's intention during a particular period?  what is hinduism's interpretation of buddha's turning of the dharma wheel?  does buddha's turning of wheel reveal a stage or sub-period in dharma evolution? is there an esoteric association with kali yuga?

Comment: limit your question to one question. The Santana Dharma is not a concept in Hinduism. Hinduism IS Santana Dharma.

Comment: Buddha cannot be answered but the stages sure can be answered.

Comment: Dharma does not change. Its following changes between Krita, Treta, Dwapara and Kali. The Dharma undergoes slight changes as per time period; [for example] certain thigs allowed in earlier Yugas not allowed in Kali.